# In onClick Event in XML , we give a method name , in which java file does the document have to be in?

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, android-button

Suppose we want to make a button do something , we may use onClick event or onClickListener

While using onClick Event in XML file , we input a method name.
Where does the method have to be located ?

Comment: In `Activity`/`Fragment` that have the layout inflated.

Comment: You mean the activity in which the setContentView is set to that XML file ? Like this -   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the activity class where the xml layout is inflated.  
It has to be `public` with this signature:

```
public void doSomething(View v) {
  //..........
}
```

In the xml of the activity, the attribute set to the `Button` must be:

```
android:onClick="doSomething"
```

The `v` parameter is actually the `View` that triggered this event,  
in your case a `Button` and you can access it by:

```
Button button = (Button) v;
```

Comment: You mean the activity in which the setContentView is set to that XML file ? Like this - setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); ?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean.